# Проблема отображения мета-тегов при ngx-mets + ngx-translate

Tags: angular5, i18n, angular, server-side-rendering

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании совместно `ngx-meta` и `ngx-translate` пакетов в [Angular Universal](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter) при выставлении на `RouterModule` `initialNavigation` со значением `'enabled'`.

Тогда при рендеринге страницы вместо мета тегов отображаются лишь значения для подставления из языкового пакета: `'HOME.TITLE'`, `'HOME.DESC'` и.т.д.

При последующем переходе, когда включается `spa`, мета подхватываются, но роли большой уже не играют. Если убрать `initialNavigation`, то при рендеринге страницы всё подхватывается хорошо, но начинается мерцание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё что нужно было сделать, это прописать `APP_INITIALIZER`. Ниже пример:

```js
export function initLanguage(translateService: TranslateService): Function {
  return (): Promise<any> => translateService.initLanguage();
}


@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initLanguage, multi: true, deps: [TranslateService] },
  ]
})
// ...
```

И на метод `initLanguage` просто выставить определение языка и т.д.